# Eclipse Tabs become greyed off when focused after changing theme

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Version  2.3.600.v20210611-1600

Since I have tried to switch and play with the themes the focused selected tab have become greyed like in this image [image].

It happens in light and classic theme.

I have tried some online solutions, without success.

Does someone has an idea?